# How to select the td where my active element is in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have got a table with a select option in it. After the select changes, the td's innerHTML should change to the selected value so the select disappears.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select onchange="update(param1, param2)">
        <option value="Value 1">Value 1</option>
        <option value="Value 1">Value 2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So, when I select Value 2, the table should look like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Value 2
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How do I do this. I've tried things like parentNode, parent()..
It has to be javascript or jQuery.

```
function update(id, row) {
    var val = document.activeElement.value;
    var id  = id;
    var row = row;

    if (val != '') {
        $.post('../inc/helikopter_beheer.php', {val: val, id: id, row: row}, function(data) {});
        $.post('../inc/gereedstelling_get_info.php', {id: id, rij: row}, function(data) {

            var result = data.split(",");
            // this.parents('id').innerHTML = result;
            $(this).closest("td").html(result[0]);
            alert(result[0]);

        });         
    };
}
```

This is what I got. It's getting some data out of my database, turns it into result and i have to get result in my td instead of the select.

Comment: Dont tell us what you've tried - show us!

Comment: It's very complicated code to display. My only question is how to select the td where my select option is in and it has to be something with this or parent I think.. since there are more td's like that in my table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select id="wdm_select">
            <option value="Value 1">Value 1</option>
            <option value="Value 2">Value 2</option>
            <option value="Value 3">Value 3</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#wdm_select").on("change",function() {
        var selected_val = $(this).val();
        $(this).parent().html( selected_val );
    })
})
</script>
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/ndczaqzz/) is demo

Answer (score 1):

JQuery function that accomplishes it (once you've given your `select` element an id of `mySelect`):

```
$('#mySelect').on('change', function () {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $(this).parent().html(val);
});
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r42Ln25q/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('change','#foo',function(){     
  $(this).parent('td').html($(this).val());
  $(this).remove();  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select id="foo">
        <option value="">--Select--</option>
        <option value="Value 1">Value 1</option>
        <option value="Value 2">Value 2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```